# Duplicate data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to keep duplicate data in my database so my question is...Is it preferable to keep the duplicate data in the same table and just add a column to identify the original data or I have to create another table to hold the copied data?

Comment: By the way, what's the purpose of having duplicate data? Just curious.

Comment: i believe he stores money in the db

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you're trying to save and why you need the duplicates? The question is a tad too broad to give a useful answer.

Comment: Then I guess it might be the fastest way to become rich overnight :p  @DombiSzabolcs

Comment: Consider reading about **database normalization** and **one to many mapping**

Comment: Please provide sample data to illustrate what you mean by "duplicate data".  Your question is not clear.

Comment: well Its an inventory and I have to manage it...here is the scenario : I have rooms to store the stuff in it....I want to store what is the stuff in what room and also I want to store the total quantity of each stuff in each room so when I sell something I can decrement the counter of it....the duplication is that to store the original data and to store the total quantity of the stuff (because I don't want to mess with the original rooms data)

Comment: That is not duplicate data, but derived or aggregated or summarised data. Strictly speaking it is redundant, but sometimes you want to keep it. (and need to maintain it ...)

Comment: that is what I am looking for @wildplasser

Comment: @GordonLinoff
sample data : http://codepad.org/jiXoWVOH
room 1, 2 ,3 represents the original data..room 0 is a special room that contains all the contents of rooms 1, 2 ,3 so that when I sell something I can decrement from room 0 and preserve the data in the other rooms...do you think this will be good?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to save the duplicate data in a different table or even a different schema so it won't be confusing to keep working with this table.

Imagine yourself in six months form now trying to guess what are all this duplicate rows for.

In addition those duplicate rows does not reflect the business purpose of this table.
It will be nicer to store them in a table named [table_name]_dup or a schema named [schema_name]_dup

Answer (score 0):

To create a backup you should read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html)

To duplicate a website with it's content. Bad solution but you still have to make a backup and restore it in a different database.

Duplicate a table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```